# Commerce product entity not being saved by EMW from another entity form submit

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I'm using the module [Commerce Stock Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock_sources) to manage different stock locations for my products.

When saving the Commerce stock sources form, on form submit, I want to update a field value on the Commerce product entity. The field is an Entity reference field.

The problem is that I can't get the field updated. No notice or error returning.

```
    //first I'm getting the values to be set; will have a simple array of IDs
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['plugins']['plugin_settings'])){
                $selected_sources = array_values(array_filter($form_state['values']['plugins']['plugin_settings']));
        }
    //next I'm loading the product entity; I have checked, the product is loading OK
    //and then the wrapper and the operations
    $product_entity = entity_load_single('commerce_product', $form_state['complete form']['#product']->product_id);
    $wrapper_product = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product_entity);
    if (!empty($selected_sources)) {
        $wrapper_product->field_product_location_store = $selected_sources;
        $wrapper_product->save();
    }
```

The field is not updated. I've checked to see if I can read values from product using `entity_metadata_wrapper()` and it works. When I try to update any field, it doesn't work.

I tried updating with `field_attach_update()`, but it doesn't work either.

```
        for($i=0; $i<count($selected_sources); $i++){
          $product_entity->field_product_location_store[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['target_id'] = $selected_sources[$i];
        }
        field_attach_update('commerce_product', $product_entity);
        entity_get_controller('commerce_product')->resetCache(array($product_entity->product_id));
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that by using the product entity directly from `$form_state['complete form']['#product'];` the `entity_metadata_wrapper()` works as expected and it saves the values.

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['plugins']['plugin_settings'])){
    $selected_sources = array_values(array_filter($form_state['values']['plugins']['plugin_settings']));
}
    //get directly the product, without entity_load_single() 
    $product_entity = $form_state['complete form']['#product']; 
    $wrapper_product = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product_entity);
    if (!empty($selected_sources)) {
        $wrapper_product->field_product_location_store = $selected_sources;
        $wrapper_product->save();
    }
```

Although the object loaded by `entity_load_single()` is identical with the object obtained by `$product_entity = $form_state['complete form']['#product'];` the `entity_metadata_wrapper()` works only for the second case, which seems more logical and is faster.